# String object in arduino becomes empty

Tags: string, post, arduino

I am using arduino to develop a small IoT project. Till now everything is working fine. 
The steps of the projects are:

1. Create an XML String from sensor reading
2. Send the XML as POST to the server.

The odd thing is that the first three trials work perfectly. However, after that, the string holding the XML becomes empty.

Below is a portion of the code:

```
void loop()
{

  while (Serial3.available()>0)
  {
    char c = Serial3.read();
    if (gps.encode(c)){
      createXML();    
      delay(1000);
      if(seconds_passed==10000 && !IsXMLEmpty)
      {
        XML+="\n</start>";
        Serial.print(XML); 
        Serial.print(F("Send to serveR"));        
        seconds_passed=0;
        IsXMLEmpty=true;
        String temp ="";
        temp = "XML="+XML;
        char *param = new char[temp.length()+1];
        temp.toCharArray(param,temp.length());
        Serial.println(param);

        if(!postPage(serverName,serverPort,pushPage,"XML=123")) Serial.print(F("Fail "));
        else Serial.print(F("Pass "));

        XML="";
        XML="<start>\n\t";
      }

    } 
  }



  // if(data==false){ Serial.println("No data"); }
}
```

I thing the problem is with the String object. It might be a memory issue. Any idea?

Comment: Nevermind I found the problem. For those who are facing the same issue, you need to deallocate the dynamically created array using  delete(param);